# Send data from android to java file of server

Tags: java, database

I'm doing my final year project and I want to send data from my Android Studio project to an external Java file of Intellij, and then from that to a database. How can I send data like images and tags from Android to an external Java file?

Comment: To avoid down votes and possible removal please post the code you've tried so far. And you might want to review this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your problem correctly, You want to Send Data from Mobile App to Java means to server where Java class file is there.

Typically any mobile app e.g. WhatsApp send Data to server via Webservice API.

You can write a REST webservice API to receive data send from Mobile App.
Typically a POST request will do.

For Image/file a Multipart REquest needs to be send.

Comment: where should i place that java file which has db connection and written at intellij

Comment: Create a WAR file of your project and deploy on any server e.g. Tomcat